# Layer Python Sum of Digits

Tags: python, algorithm

this is my first question around here.

I've been working on an algorithm that adds the numbers entered until I get a single-digit number, but haven't been able to find a solution for about a week.

for example:

```
value = 1994
```

1. Step = 1+9+9+4 = 23
2. Step = 2+3 = 5

Comment: You should show your code and what was the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def func(x):
    while x >= 10:
        x = sum([int(c) for c in str(x)])
    return x

print(func(1994))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.
For the 1994 issue, this code works, but what about if the sum of the digits of the entered number again creates a two-digit number?

Comment: @Emre: Isn't that the case for 1994??? Please provide an example for which this solution doesn't work.

Comment: I am so sorry for not being able to explain what I wanted to do. but I can say that I am constantly trying to add a four-digit number and reduce the result to a single digit. For example, the code you provided works fine for 1994, but when I enter another 4-digit number in 1999, it comes out as 10 from the code block. but what I am trying to do is use this number 10 as 1 + 0 = 1.

Comment: @Emre: Yes, my mistake, change `x > 10` to `x >= 10`.

Comment: I wish you could see my current state. I'm so happy Thank you very much for your interest and help. I hope someday I can be as knowledgeable as you, my dear master.

Comment: @Emre: hahahahaha you're welcome , feel free to accept this as the answer to your question by clicking on the V next to it.

Comment: Thank you so much again sir. Just please show me a road map to learn this language.

Comment: I must admit that I didn't read the documentation from my learning pattern. I watched watching videos and worked on applications. If I will be 10 percent of you, I will sit down and memorize it from the beginning: D

Answer (score 0):

```
value = 1994
while len(str(value)) != 1:
  value = sum([int(i) for i in str(value)])

print(value)
```

```
5
```

What's going on?

- initiate value
- loop if the length of the integer is not equal to one (meaning it's done)
- get a sum of the list of all sub ints inside the int

Comment: That's just one round. You need to continue until the result is a single digit.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. İ can't rate you for now. But 
Thank you very much for your interest